# Nest JS new project error Failed to execute command

Tags: npm, nestjs

I am new to nest.js, I've been trying to create a new project but I'm facing the same error.

Node version is : 14.15.3
Nest js version is : 9.2.0
Npm version is : 6.14.9

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Personal-Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\host.js
- C:\Users\Personal-Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Personal-Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics-cli\bin\schematics.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Personal-Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\host.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Personal-Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\node\\host.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Personal-Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\node\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Personal-Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\schematics-cli\\bin\\schematics.js'
  ]
}

Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:application --name=demo --directory=undefined 
--no-dry-run --no-skip-git --no-strict --package-manager="npm" --collection="@nestjs/schematics" --language="ts"
```

I have tried installing the clearing the cache, uninstalling & re-installing nest, installing schematics. But nothing seems to be working, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g @nestjs/cli
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
npm i -g @nestjs/schematics
nest new demo
```

I also tried with npx `npx @nestjs/cli new demo` but still getting the same error.

Comment: I believe you should upgrade your nodejs to 14.18. See: https://2ality.com/2021/12/node-protocol-imports.html#support-for-node%3A-imports

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce it by downgrading my Node to v14.15.3, try updating Nodejs and that should work

If you are using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
> nvm install 14
> nvm use 14

Now using node v14.21.3 (npm v6.14.18)

> npm i -g @nestjs/cli

+ @nestjs/cli@9.2.0
added 255 packages from 249 contributors in 58.51s

> nest new demo

⚡  We will scaffold your app in a few seconds..

CREATE demo/.eslintrc.js (665 bytes)
CREATE demo/.prettierrc (51 bytes)
```